# get_object causes a ton of MySQL queries in my Django app

Tags: python, django

I am experiencing issues with MySQL queries. I've added get_object into MediaDetailView to achieve two slugs in URL pattern. This has increased the number of MySQL queries.

The MySQL queries have gone from 6 to 36 and need 3ms to fetch all data from the database. As the website becomes filled with more content, the app produces even more MySQL queries.

Within a Type model, I have three entries: channels, rooms, and groups. The objective is to create a URL structure such as localhost:8000/type_slug/handle_slug. - Here, the term "handle" is essentially regarded as the slug.

MediaIndex cause all the MySQL queries. It is a view for the main/root page so it's important to optimize it.

I use Django Debug Toolbar to analyze performance. (I don't see more info because I'm getting: 404: Not Found error). I would really appreciate if someone helps. Thanks in advance.

**PYTHON**

**views.py**

```
class MediaDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Media
    template_name = 'media_detail.html'
    
    # get_object may cause the issue ?!
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        type_slug = self.kwargs.get('type_slug')
        media_slug = self.kwargs.get('media_slug')
        media = get_object_or_404(Media, type__slug=type_slug, handle=media_slug)
        return media

class MediaIndex(ListView):
    model = Media
    template_name = 'media/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'media_list'
    paginate_by = 200
```

**models.py**

```
class Type(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Media(models.Model):
    # Fields for the Media model
    handle = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField(null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**urls.py**

```
  urlpatterns = [
        path('', MediaIndex.as_view(), name='media'), #media/dir
        path('<slug:type_slug>/<slug:media_slug>/', MediaDetailView.as_view(), name='media_detail'),

    ]
```

**TEMPLATES:**

Note: If I remove url from templates, queries are back to normal!

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% include 'media/media.html' %}

{% include 'media/channels.html' %}

{%  endblock %}
```

**media.html**

```
{% for media in page_obj %}
<div class="column is-one-quarter-widescreen is-one-third-desktop is-half-tablet is-full-mobile ">
    <a href="{% url 'media_detail' type_slug=media.type.slug media_slug=media.handle %}"> # <= this causes problems
        <div class="card featured">
        <span class="featured-label">
          <span class="tag sponsored is-size-7">Sponsored</span>
        </span>
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <figure class="image is-64x64">
            <img src="/{{ media.thumb_path }}" class="is-rounded">
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="media-content">
            <p class="title is-size-6 two-line-text">{{media.name}}</p>
            <p class="subtitle is-size-7 has-text-grey ">
            <i class="fas fa-at"></i> {{media.handle}} </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        <div class="columns is-mobile is-flex-touch">
            <div class="column is-8">
            <p class="subtitle is-size-7"><i class="fas fa-robot"></i> {{ media.category }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <p class="subtitle is-size-7"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> 
                    {% if media.subscribers_count %} {{ media.subscribers_count }} 
                    {% elif media.members_count %}  {{ media.members_count }} {% endif %}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**channels.html**

```
  {% for channel in channels %}
  <div class="column is-one-quarter-widescreen is-one-third-desktop is-half-tablet is-full-mobile ">
    <a href="{% url 'media_detail' type_slug=channel.media.type.slug media_slug=channel.media.handle %}"> # <= this causes problems
      <div class="card featured">
          <span class="featured-label">
            <span class="tag sponsored is-size-7">Sponsored</span>
          </span>
      <div class="card-content">
          <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
              <figure class="image is-64x64">
              <img src="/{{ channel.media.thumb_path }}" class="is-rounded">
              </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="media-content">
              <p class="title is-size-6 two-line-text">{{channel.media.name}}</p>
              <p class="subtitle is-size-7 has-text-grey ">
              <i class="fas fa-at"></i> {{channel.media.handle}}</p>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="content">
          <div class="columns is-mobile is-flex-touch">
              <div class="column is-8">
              <p class="subtitle is-size-7"><i class="fas fa-robot"></i> {{ channel.media.category}}
              </p>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                  <p class="subtitle is-size-7"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> {{ channel.subscribers }}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a classic  N+1 query problem. When you access a related model's fields, like media.type.slug in the template, Django will retrieve the related Type object from the database for each media object, thus generating a separate query.

The solution is to optimize your queries using Django's [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) methods.

For your case, in the MediaIndex view, maybe try something like this to overwrite the default get_queryset:

```
class MediaIndex(ListView):
    model = Media
    template_name = 'media/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'media_list'
    paginate_by = 200
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Media.objects.select_related('type', 'category', 'language').all()
```

This way the related type, category, and language objects will already be fetched in the initial query.

The key is to optimize your queries so you fetch all the necessary data in as few database hits as possible.  Always analyze the SQL queries that Django is generating (Django Debug Toolbar is great for this) and look for places to optimize.